# Скрипт перестаёт работать после вставки ссылки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть такой код, одна большая картинка, под ней три маленьких превьюшки.
При наведении мышкой на превьюшку, она отображается вместо большой картинки.

```
<div class="an_image">
        <img src="0.jpg">
          <div class="preview">
              <img src="sm1.jpg" data-src="1.jpg">
              <img src="sm2.jpg" data-src="2.jpg">
              <img src="sm3.jpg" data-src="3.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>
```

Нашёл кусок скрипта, который отвечает за всё это дело.

```
t(".preview img").mouseenter(function(){t(this).parent().prev().attr("src",t(this).data().src)})
```

Так вот, надо обернуть большую картинку ссылкой,

```
<a href="#>
    <img src="0.jpg">
        </a>
```

но тогда перестают меняться превьюшки. Что дописать?

Comment: Еще один `parent()` добавить

Comment: Не работает. ____ t(".preview img").mouseenter(function(){t(this).parent().parent().prev().attr("src",t(this).data().src)}),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t(".preview img").mouseenter(function(){
    var newSrc = t(this).attr("src")
    t('.an_image > img').attr('src', newSrc)
})
```

Comment: Не, что-то не то. Кстати, я не упомянул, извините, что на странице есть ещё несколько таких же элементов. Так вот сейчас получается, что, при наведении на превьюшку, меняются картинки на всех остальных, не обрамлённых ссылкой, картинках, а эта остаётся неизменной. Точки с запятой в конце строк я добавил.

Comment: Тогда нужно исправить третью строчку на : t(this).parents('.an_image').find('img').first().attr('src', newSrc)

Comment: Или добавить к большой картинке класс какой-то:
t(this).parents('.an_image').find('.big_image').attr('src', newSrc)

Comment: t(this).parents('.an_image').find('img').first().attr('src', newSrc) ____ Так работает, спасибо.